# point in multiple polygons

Tags: python, cartography, web-mapping, sql-server

I have a `point` (lat/lng) and a collection of `geofences` (polygons / circles / rectangles)

Simply put, I want to know if the point is inside **ANY** of the geofences, it's not important which one.

I know how to solve this comparing the point against each geofence, the problem is that I'm drawing a [`heat map`](http://leaflet.github.io/Leaflet.heat/demo/) with +750000 points that needs to be checked against 800 geofences.

Needless to say, the brute-force approach of comparing each point against each geofence will not cut it.

I was thinking along the lines of drawing all the geofences in a plane (something like a raster but based on X / Y coordinates) and then see if the point touches a painted area, but looks like a long shot and I'm not math oriented enough to write ray-tracing algorithms.

All of this is beign done in `SQL Server 2008 R2`, no GIS library, just `int` (point / circle / rect) and `varbinary` for the polygons

How can I solve this?

Comment: SQL Server has built in geographic spatial queries and functions. [This website](http://www.bostongis.com/PrinterFriendly.aspx?content_name=sql2008_tut01) (pardon the tutorial title) may be helpful for you to get up and running with different spatial queries and functions